# How to retrieve attributes of a resource using AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk

I have a AWS::RDS::DBInstance and I need to get the Endpoint.Address attribute. Normally in Cloudformation I could simply use `Fn::GetAtt: [MyRdsInstance, Endpoint.Address]` but I need to fetch this from AWS API directly. Is there a way to retrieve this attribute (or any attribute associated with a Resource) via the API? Ideally I'd like a generic endpoint that can be used on any resource and it is also ok if it returns a list of attributes rather than single.

The closest I can see is [DescribeStackResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStackResource.html) but it doesn't contain attributes.

Comment: Use `DescribeStackResource` to get the physical ID, then `RDS.describe_db_instances()` with filter on that ID to get the `Endpoint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get this info from your stacks, you have to modify your templates and [output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) these details.

Then using, [describe-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) you can query your stack for the `Outputs`.